# How to evaluate and compile such a function using theano or autowrap?

Tags: python, sympy, theano

I would like to evaluate functions of similar form (more complicated) in sympy.

```
y = a * b / np.sum( a*( b + c) )
```

where all variables are vectors of length `n`. The evaluation will take place at every timestep of an optimization routine. As a consequence, I would like to implement it efficiently. Most probably, it would be best to compile those functions but the autowrap module gives me strange errors.

What works:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from __future__ import division

a = sp.IndexedBase('a')
b = sp.IndexedBase('b')
c = sp.IndexedBase('c')

n = 4
expr_fun = lambda x:  a[x] * (b[x] + c[x])
expr = [ a[i]*b[i] / np.sum([expr_fun(i) for i in range(n)]) for i in range(n)]
```

I can evaluate this expression directly in sympy:

```
r = np.random.random(n)
subs_dict = {}
[  subs_dict.update({a[i]:r[i],b[i]:r[i] }) for i in range(n) ]

[expr[i].subs(subs_dict) for i in range(n)]
```

Gives me (as expected):

`0.0786923966864026*c[0] + 0.403977159637609*c[1] + 0.598011208186539*c[2] + 0.0896229978341944*c[3] + 0.535039725662632`

But I failed at compiling this expression. I am reading blogs and manuals since hours, but either I am too tired or did not find the proper information. Any help is strongly appreciated.

EDIT: In response to Eric: I do not now how to implement the sum of a vector in theano or autowrap. I tried different versions using lambda functions and got various errors. Maybe the most reproducible has to do with the dimension of the inputs:

```
from sympy.printing.theanocode import theano_function
from sympy.printing.theanocode import sympy as sp
from sympy.printing.theanocode import dim_handling
import numpy as np

symbols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a, b, c, d = map(sp.Symbol, symbols )
expr = a + b*(c+d)/np.sum(b + c*d)
n = 1
dim = {} # collections.OrderedDict()
[dim.update( {i: n} ) for i in [a, b, c, d] ]

dt = {} # collections.OrderedDict()
[dt.update( {i: 'float64'} ) for i in [a, b, c, d] ]

f = theano_function( [a, b, c, d], [expr], dims = dim, dtypes=dt )

in_var = np.array([ [1,2,3,4] ])
f(in_var.T)

TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 1, got 2 with shape (4, 1).')
```

If I try to compile a simple expression using autowrap:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import autowrap
m, n = sp.symbols('m n', integer=True)
a, b, c,d = map(sp.IndexedBase, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
i = sp.Idx('i',m)
j = sp.Idx('j',n)
instruction = sp.Eq(a[i], b[i]*(c[i] + d[i]) )
f = autowrap(instruction)
```

I obtain:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 3749: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What exactly is failing? What error does it fail with?

Answer (score 1):

There are mulitple issues with your approach. 1) You can't mix in numpy functions with SymPy types and then expect the code generators to work with the mixed types. The code generators in SymPy work with SymPy types only. You can pass in external functions that map to SymPy functions. For example, you can use sympy.Sum() and then write a mapping from SymPy.Sum() to numpy.sum() for the code generator to consume. 2) Eq() is not supported in code generators as far as I know. 3) The indexed types do very specific things when passed to autowrap. You'll need to read the docs carefully about them.